# Função Dinâmica PHP

Tags: php

Como eu reformulo essa função para fazer um `select` em mais de uma tabela, de forma dinâmica ?

```
  public function Lista(){
        $results = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'tabela'");
        $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt) {
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    $not = new Not();
                    $not->setid($row->ID);
                    $not->setimg1($row->Img1);
                    $not->setimg2($row->Img2);
                    $not->setimg3($row->Img3);
                    $results[] = $not;
                }
            }
        return $results;
    }
```

Pois preciso de vários select's em várias tabelas não encontrei um jeito simples, a não ser fazer uma função para cada select. O mesmo se repete para `update` e `insert`. Alguma dica ?

Comment: Já pensou em passar para a função o nome da tabela como  argumento? no `prepare` você faz algo assim: `"SELECT * FROM '$nomeTabela'"`.

Comment: Pesquise sobre Inner Join ou union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que queira algo assim.

```
 public function Lista($tabela){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM '$tabela'";
        $results = array();
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt) {
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                    $not = new Not();
                    $not->setid($row->ID);
                    $not->setimg1($row->Img1);
                    $not->setimg2($row->Img2);
                    $not->setimg3($row->Img3);
                    $results[] = $not;
                }
            }
        return $results;
    }
```

Para passar o valor da tabela, basta escrever seu nome no momento de chamar a função **Lista()** como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Lista('usuario');
```

Assim a função retorna dados da tabela usuario

Comment: Entendi, como é que eu passo um valor para essa `$tabela` ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com um exemplo